# How to refresh the Jcombobox each selection?

Tags: java

```
 public class dropit extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
   JComboBox lis,pop;
   Map<String,String[]>map=new TreeMap<String,String[]>();
   JTextField tf;
   String days[]={"sun","mon","tue","wed","thur","fri","sat"};
   String mon[]={"man","van"};
   String tue[]={"car","bus"};
dropit()
 {
    setLayout(null);
    tf=new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    add(tf);
    map.put("mon", mon);
    map.put("tue",tue);
    lis=new JComboBox(days);
    lis.setSelectedItem(4);
    lis.addActionListener(this);
    lis.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    add(lis);


    /*pop=new JComboBox();
    pop.setBounds(200,100 , 100, 100);
    add(pop);*/
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    lis=(JComboBox) e.getSource();
    String name=(String) lis.getSelectedItem();
    tf.setText(name);
    Iterator<String>iter=map.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        String arryname=iter.next();
        String []array=map.get(arryname);
        if(arryname.contains(name))
        {
            pop=new JComboBox(array);
            pop.setBounds(200,100 , 100, 100);
            add(pop)
          }}
       pop.repaint();
       pop.revalidate();
      }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    new dropit();
          }}
```

The combo box is working perfectly but the populating values in the next combo box is just working only for the first time

I tried repaint revalidate but not working

help me solve this .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never remove the first `pop` created, so it hides the other ones.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    lis = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
    String name = (String) lis.getSelectedItem();
    tf.setText(name);

    if (map.containsKey(name))
    {
        if (pop != null)
            this.remove(pop);
        pop = new JComboBox(map.get(name));
        pop.setBounds(200,100 , 100, 100);
        add(pop);
    }
}
```

Or instead of adding and removing the JComboBox, you could just empty and refill it, hiding it when `map` doesn't contain the key.

```
Dropit()
{
    setLayout(null);
    tf = new JTextField();
    tf.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    add(tf);
    map.put("mon", mon);
    map.put("tue", tue);
    lis = new JComboBox<String>(days);
    lis.setSelectedItem("sat");
    lis.addActionListener(this);
    lis.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    add(lis);


    pop = new JComboBox<String>();
    pop.setBounds(200,100 , 100, 100);
    pop.setVisible(false);
    add(pop);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500,500);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    lis = (JComboBox<String>) e.getSource();
    String name = (String) lis.getSelectedItem();
    tf.setText(name);

    if (map.containsKey(name))
    {
        pop.removeAllItems();
        for (String s: map.get(name))
            pop.addItem(s);
        pop.setVisible(true);
    } else 
        pop.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: @sukesh I've just edited the post. What's your IDE? What's the error?

Comment: I'm using eclipse 
The error is 
The second combo box not showing

Comment: @sukesh Do you want to append every combo box? So if you select "mon", then "tue", you'll see 3 combo box.  Or do you want that every time you change the first one, the second one shows the correct list?

Comment: I just need to populate the value to the next combo box

It works only when first selection 
When I select tue it remain same
I tried request focus it just showed the first value  but then clicking a drop-down shows the first array value

Comment: @sukesh I've tested it in Eclipse and the second combo box is populated with the right values every time I change the selection in the first one.  
by "clicking a drop-down shows the first array value" do you mean that the value in textField doesn't change?